# TypeScript 2.1 async/await ES5 __awaiter and __generator is generated for every ts file

Tags: typescript, webpack, async-await, typescript2.1

I'm experimenting with the new rc-release of TypeScript to get the asnc/await support for ES5.

But I experience a strange behavior with the generated __awaiter and __generator methods, it seems they are generated for every single ts file if the outFile compiler option is not used.

Is there a way to generate only a single instance of the __awaiter and __generator methods while still not using outFile?
The reason why I don't want to use the outFile flag is that I currently use webpack for bundling as I need to support importing of HTML template files.

Comment: you can use common chunks plugin + deddupe plugin, which will reduce this duplication

Answer (score 4):

Use the new `--importHelpers` compile flag.
[Docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#support-for-external-helpers-library-tslib)

Answer (score 4):

- In *tsconfig.json*, under `"compilerOptions"` add:

  ```
  `"importHelpers": true`
  ```
- install the typescript helper library as a dependency:

  ```
  npm install tslib --save
  ```

Typescript will attempt to import the helpers when needed and Webpack will automatically bundle tslib once. If you are publishing a library you can tell webpack to consider `tslib` an external with [the `externals` option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals).